# Java: How can I make a ball behave as a bouncing and elastic ball?

Tags: java

I have two classes `BouncingBall` and another one called `ElasticBall`. Both classes extends `BallImpl` which implements an interface called `Ball`.

```
public interface Ball {
    int DEFAULT_RADIUS = 50;

    int radius();
    Point center();
    void update();
}

public class BouncingBall extends BallImpl {
    public static final int MOVEMENT_SPEED = 12;

    static final int DOWN = 1;
    static final int UP = -1;

    private int direction;

    BouncingBall(int x, int y, int direction) {
        super(x, y);
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        direction = reverseDirectionIfNecessary();
        y = move();
    }

    private int reverseDirectionIfNecessary() {
        if (movingTooHigh() || movingTooLow()) {
            return switchDirection();
        }

        return this.direction;
    }

    private boolean movingTooLow() {
        return y + radius >= BallWorld.BOX_HEIGHT && movingDown();
    }

    private boolean movingTooHigh() {
        return y - radius <= 0 && movingUp();
    }

    private int switchDirection() {
        return movingDown() ? UP : DOWN;
    }

    private int move() {
        return y + (MOVEMENT_SPEED * direction);
    }

    private boolean movingDown() {
        return direction == DOWN;
    }

    private boolean movingUp() {
        return direction == UP;
    }
}

public class ElasticBall extends BallImpl {
    public static final int GROWTH_RATE = 2;

    static final int GROW = 1;
    static final int SHRINK = -1;

    private int growthDirection;

    ElasticBall(int x, int y, int radius, int growthDirection) {
        super(x, y, radius);
        this.growthDirection = growthDirection;
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        growthDirection = reverseGrowthDirectionIfNecessary();
        radius = next();
    }

    private int reverseGrowthDirectionIfNecessary() {
        if (growingTooBig() || shrinkingTooSmall()) {
            return switchDirection();
        }

        return this.growthDirection;
    }

    private boolean shrinkingTooSmall() {
        return radius <= 0 && shrinking();
    }

    private boolean growingTooBig() {
        return radius >= Ball.DEFAULT_RADIUS && growing();
    }

    private int switchDirection() {
        return growing() ? SHRINK : GROW;
    }

    private int next() {
        return radius + (GROWTH_RATE * growthDirection);
    }

    private boolean shrinking() {
        return growthDirection == SHRINK;
    }

    private boolean growing() {
        return growthDirection == GROW;
    }
}
```

I need to create a `BouncingElasticBall` which combines the behavior of the `BouncingBall` and the `ElasticBall` classes. I have poor knowledge in OOP, and I know Java does not allow multiple inheritance, so how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you inherit `BouncingElasticBall` from one of them, without having to have 2 super classes? Why do you need them both separate?

Comment: From a design point of view, you can have `ElasticBall` and `BouncingBall` _implement_ the `Ball` interface rather than extending a superclass.  From a physics point of view, I don't know offhand how to make your balls bounce.

Comment: This kind of requirements are stupid. The best way to come up with solution is, as always, composition. What if you now want a `RedElasticBouncingBall` and a `YellowRollingBall`? Gonna create all classes until all combinations are covered? No: use composition. Have a ball, several behaviors you can reuse and be done with it. Tell whoever designed this that he/she doesn't understand the concept of OOP. It's *object oriented* programming, not *full object* programming.

Comment: Consider rewording your question. It sounds like you are asking about physics, but actually this is really a "how do I proper OO design" question.

Comment: The key is in your question: when you want *behaviour* you should immediately think *interfaces*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you could approach this is to *not extend* `BallImpl`, but make sort-of *plugins*. Like this:

```java
public class BallImpl implements Ball {
    List<BallBehavior> behaviors = ...

    @Override
    public void update() {
       behaviors.forEach(behavior -> behavior.update(this));
    }
    ...
}

public interface BallBehavior {
    void update(BallImpl ballImpl);
}
```

And then, just write your elastic and bouncing logic as *behaviors*.

Comment: Side note: in pattern language, that is called the visitor pattern. And in my opinion, your answer is the one that is the best option to solve the original problem.

Comment: I would even go as far as creating a `ComposedBallBehavior` to do the for-loop, allowing only one `BallBehavior` in the class, not a list of them.

Answer (score 2):

Once you diverge hierarchies there's no way to merge them in java.

It's a design matter: if you know that `ElasticBall` and `BouncingBall` may be combined together, you should create two interfaces `Elastic` and `Bouncing`, both extending interface `Ball`, with common methods valid for both.

Then the common method implementations may be set into a common abstract class, let's say `AbstractBall`. At this point you can finally detail your three implementations:

- `ElasticBall extends AbstractBall implements Elastic`
- `BouncingBall extendis AbstractBall implements Bouncing`
- `ElasticBouncingBall extends AbstractBall implements Elastic, Bouncing`

In this way you'll be able to control what to do in each method, reuse code for common stuff (in the abstract class).

Answer (score 1):

You can use interfaces that allows multiple inheritance. Make the interface for each ball`ElasticBall` and `BouncingBall` and implement both of them in `BouncingElasticBall`.